# My screen will not repaint despite the rectangle being clicked

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, collision

I have my code set up to where the Boolean boxDetect will be set to true if the mouse is clicked within the Rectangle startButton. The rest is just formatting nothing special! This is the initial screen before you press inside the rectangle, and once inside the rectangle and pressed it should repaint the screen to a rectangle at points 400,400.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.*;

public class spaceInvadersIntroScreen implements MouseListener
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private MyPanel panel;
    private double startButtonX = 0;
    private double startButtonY = 0;
    private Rectangle startButton;
    private Boolean boxDetect = false;

public static void main(String[] args){ new spaceInvadersIntroScreen(); }

public spaceInvadersIntroScreen()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Space Invaders");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    startButtonX = screenSize.getWidth() / 2; //Finds the X value of the center of the screen
    startButtonY = screenSize.getHeight() / 2; //Finds the Y value of the center of the screen
    frame.setSize(screenSize); //width and height
    panel = new MyPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    startButton = new Rectangle((int)(startButtonX - 200), (int)(startButtonY - 75), 400, 150); //Creates Rectangle in the middle of the screen
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

    if(boxDetect == false)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; 
        //Background 
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0,0, 1440, 870);

        //Code for an X centered title regardless of the screen length

        String title = "SPACE INVADERS";
        Font textFont = new Font("monospaced", Font.BOLD, 150);
        FontMetrics textMetrics = g2d.getFontMetrics(textFont);  
        g2d.setFont(textFont);   

        int centeredX = (this.getWidth()/2) - (textMetrics.stringWidth(title)/2);   

        //Prints SPACE INVADERS to the screen
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.setFont(textFont);
        g2d.drawString(title, centeredX, 200);

        //draw the Button
        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.fill(startButton); 
    }

    else
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(400, 400, 400, 400);
    }

    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
{
    double xCoord = e.getX();
    double yCoord = e.getY();
    if(startButton.contains(xCoord,yCoord) == true)
    {
        boxDetect = true;
    }
    panel.repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I am a new programmer, this being my first year so I'm always forgetting the little things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ***add*** the MouseListener for it to work. Question: Where do you call `addMouseListener(...)`? Answer: you don't. Solution: make this method call to add the MouseListener to the component that needs it.